# Question related to the General equilibrium in exchange economies

Tags: game-theory, economics

I need some help in solving this question:

Consider the following two-person, two-good economy. Persons $A$ and $B$ each consume two goods xylophones $(x)$ and yams $(y)$. Person $A$ enters the world with $14$ units of xylophones and $1$ unit of yams, person $B$ with $0$ units of xylophones and $4$ units of yams. Their utility functions are given by:

$U^A(x^A,y^A) = \frac{x^Ay^A}{x^A + y^A}$ and $U^B(x^B,y^B)=ln(x^B)+ln(y^B)$.

$(a)$ Construct an Edgeworth box diagram to illustrate the feasible consumption possibilites. Label the initial endowment point.

My solution: [image]

$(b)$ Find the equation of the contract curve, expressed in terms of goods consumed by person A. There is no need to solve for $y^A$ explicitly in terms of $x^A$.

My attempt: I have to solve the following equations:

1. $MRS_{xy}^A =  MRS_{xy}^B$
2. $x^A + x^B =14$
3. $y^A + y^B=5$

After some computations, I have found that $MRS_{xy}^A = \frac{y^{A^{2}}}{x^{A^{2}}}$ and $ MRS_{xy}^B= \frac{y^{B}}{x^{B}}$. So if $MRS_{xy}^A =  MRS_{xy}^B$ we can manipulate equation 1. to write equation 4.: $y^{B}=\frac{y^{A^{2}}x^B}{x^{A^{2}}}$.

In equation 2.: $x^A + x^B =14\Rightarrow x^B=14 - x^A$.

In equation 3. $y^A + y^B=5\Rightarrow y^B=5 - y^A$.

Substitute in $x^B=14 - x^A$ and $y^B=5 - y^A$ in equation 4. to get: $5-y^A=\frac{y^{A^{2}}(14-x^{A})}{x^{A^{2}}} \Rightarrow y^{A(A-1)} = 5 - \frac{\left ( 14-x^A \right )}{x^{A^{2}}}$.

Is this the equation of the contract curve?

$(c)$ Describe the core of this economy.

$(d)$ Find the competitive equilibrium outcome, given the initial endowments. Is it on the
contract curve? Explain.

Comment: This "question" is the whole essence of general equilibrium in exchange economies. So "need some help" means "need some help to understand the whole theory". Please narrow the scope, and provide some tentative approaches that you think solve the various sub-questions.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos For your information, I understand the theory of GE, but having problems graphing the utility functions.

Comment: Your Edgeworth box diagram is correct. To graph the utility functions, fix a numerical value for the utility and solve for, say, $x$ as a function of $y$ and of this numerical fixed value.

Comment: Any suggestions on how I can find the competitive equilibrium outcome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The contract curve is where the MRS of both agents coincide. So compute FOC's for two agents. Set them equal.

The core are allocations which, assuming the given endowment, are both individual rational and coalition-rational. Individual rationality can be deduced from the respective indifference curves. You will see an olive-shaped region. Coalition-rationality in this case just means the contract curve.

Comment: Any suggestions on how I can find the competitive equilibrium outcome?

Comment: The competitive equilibrium outcome, like always, is a set of prices. For any given price, your agents have demands for the two goods. You need to find the prices such that the market clears.

Comment: @Michael: this might seem like punctilious formalism but a competitive (or Walrasian) equilibrium is not only a price vector. It is rather a price vector and an allocation satisfying a set of conditions. In general, an equilibrium price vector can be associated with multiple competitive equilibria, although it is not an issue here because the utility function are strictly quasi-concave.

Comment: Ok, fair point.